# Which Bluetooth profiles Android SDK supports

Tags: android, bluetooth

Out of the profiles listed in the following link which ones are supported by android SDK:
https://support.google.com/ics/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650159

From the documentation it seems the support for bluetooth profiles with android SDK is very limited:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html

Thanks

Comment: Did you got any option to communicate with a 3rd party Bluetooth device, other than using RFCOMM method? I'd like to know is there any work-around. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`sdptool`](http://examplenow.com/sdptool/usage)? You can issue the command even from an ADB shell. This should give you a good idea of the bluetooth profiles supported by your device.

I believe Android SDK provides public APIs for the RFCOMM, A2DP, and HDP bluetooth profiles.

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex, no I'm not interested in knowing about profiles my device supports, I want to connect to another 3rd party bluetooth device from my android code so I understand the way to do it is to go through a bluetooth profile but if Android SDK supports only 3 profiles then that seems like a limitation ?

Comment: A2DP and HDP are specific to audio headsets and health device profiles so it sounds like you want to use RFCOMM. I guess it's a limitation in that you are forced to use it, but then again you know for a fact that all devices will support it and there is a lot of documentation on how to implement a bluetooth server to connect to another device... have you google searched "android bluetooth" and read the article that pops up?

Comment: Yes I've read the article, I mentioned that I want to connect to another 3rd party bluetooth device so what I meant to say was I don't have the option to run a bluetooth server on the other device. I understand RFCOMM communication would only be possible when a serversocket is listening for connections on the 3rd party bluetooth device?